# How to create a friendship matrix for 1,5 million users in python?

Tags: python, matrix

My task is to create a friendship matrix (user-user matrix), which values are 1, if the users are friends, and 0, if not. My .csv file have 1,5 million rows, so I create the following little csv to test my algorithm:

```
user_id              friends
   Elena          Peter, John
   Peter          Elena, John
   John           Elena, Peter, Chris
   Chris          John
```

For this little csv, my code works well:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

from scipy import sparse

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

user_filepath = 'H:\\YelpData\\test.csv' # this is my little test file

df = pd.read_csv(user_filepath, usecols=['user_id','friends'])

def Convert_String_To_List(string):
    if string!="None":
        li = list(string.split(", ")) 
    else:
        li = []
    return li 

friend_map = {}

for i in range(len(df)): #storing friendships in map
    friend_map[df['user_id'][i]] = Convert_String_To_List(df['friends'][i])

users = sorted(friend_map.keys()) 
user_indices = dict(zip(users, range(len(users)))) #giving indices for users

#and now the sparsity matrix:

row_ind = [] #row indices, where the value is 1
col_ind = [] #col indices, where the value is 1
data = []    # value 1

for user in users:
    for barat in baratok[user]:
        row_ind.append(user_indices[user])
        col_ind.append(user_indices[barat])

for i in range(len(row_ind)):
    data.append(1)

mat_coo = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)))

friend_matrix = mat_coo.toarray() #this friendship matrix is good for the little csv file
```

But when I try this code to my large (1,5 million rows) csv, I get memory error, when I want to store friendships in map (in the for cycle).

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Does this mean you have 1.5 m of distinct names from which you would like to generate a matrix that is 1.5 m x 1.5 m?

Comment: Yes, this is my task. Friendship matrix for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are approaching this the wrong way, you should use `pandas` and vectorized operation as possible to account for the large data you have.

This is a complete `pandas` approach depending on your data.

```
import pandas as pd

_series = df1.friends.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(', '))).unstack().dropna()
data = pd.Series(_series.values, index=_series.index.droplevel(0))
pd.get_dummies(data).groupby('user_id').sum()
```

**Output**

```
        Chris   Elena   John    Peter
user_id             
Chris   0          0    1        0
Elena   0          0    1        1
John    1          1    0        1
Peter   0          1    1        0
```

BTW, this can be further optimized and through using `pandas` you avoid using memory-expensive for loops and you can use `chunksize` to chunk your data for furthere optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not store the string repeatedly. You need to make a list of name and store the index of the name, not the name itself. This part of the code:

```
friend_map[df['user_id'][i]] = Convert_String_To_List(df['friends'][i])
```

can be changed. If you have a list of users,

```
users = [....] # read from csv
friend_list = Convert_String_To_List(df['friends'][i])
friend_list_idxs = Get_Idx_of_Friends(users,friend_list) #look up table users
friend_map[df['user_id'][i]] = friend_list_idxs
```

This way, you will not need to store same string repeatedly.

Let's say you have 10 million friend relationship, you will need to store 10MB of memory.